# What units are needed for the variables when I want the result to be in $erg$

Tags: units, unit-conversion

$erg$ is an Energy unit, which means that it is equal to $\frac{mass{\cdot}distance^2}{time^2}$. If I want to calculate the kinetic energy of a body in erg units, in what units should the distance and mass be?

By "what units" I mean $kg$ or $gram$ and $cm$, $m$ or $km$ not $inch$ vs. $m$.

Comment: 1 erg is $10^{-7}$ joules, so $1\;\text{erg} = 10^{-7}\;\text{kg}\,\text{m}^2\,\text{s}^{-2}$.

Comment: @Pulsar, why is it not an answer?

Comment: A comment is more suitable for 1 line of info. Answers are more appropriate for longer explanations.

Comment: @Pulsar: Then, *I'd argue that it's definitely not what you think*. Of course, I've seen line-answers (cruelly, even word-answers). It gets in the low-quality review queue and we just say it *looks good*. There's no rule that small answers should be written as comments ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CGS units:
grams and cm, as you asked.